# Mysql multiple AND and one OR

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query

```
SELECT time FROM logs WHERE (pstatus!=\"6\" OR ptype!=\"7\") AND uid=\"$id\" AND project=\"$pid\"  GROUP BY project;
```

I wanna get only values(time) which ignores rows that has pstatus=6 or ptype=7.
What am i doing wrong here as it currently prints all values.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using single quotes? Like

```
SELECT time FROM logs WHERE pstatus!='6' AND ptype!='7'
AND uid='$id' AND project='$pid' GROUP BY project;
```

Also, if you want to exclude rows where "pstatus=6 or ptype=7" then the negated form must use `AND`.

Comment: As a side note also the group by is completely useless since he is fetching data for a single project and doesn't use any aggregated function